# Is it possible binding a property from VM to a local property in the controller, using MVVMCross 4 and Xamarin.iOS

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, local-variables

I have a local string variable in my controller and would like to bind it to a property in my ViewModel (core). I have tried:

```cs
private string culture;
var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<OnBoardingViewController, OnBoardingViewModel>();
bindings.Bind(culture).For(x => x).To(viewmodel => viewmodel.LanguageCode);
bindings.Apply();
```

It doesn't succeed. 
Is it possible bind a local variable using MvvmCross or just components properties?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Property `MyProperty`on your ViewController and bind it like:

```cs
var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<OnBoardingViewController, OnBoardingViewModel>();
bindings.Bind(this).For(x => x.MyProperty).To(viewmodel => viewmodel.LanguageCode);
bindings.Apply();
```

MvvMCross needs the expression in `For` to extract the property name. And this expression has to be in the form `x => x.Property`, or `x => x.Property.SubProperty`, etc. And the second problem is, that local variables are -as their name suggests- local. So they will get cleaned up, when you leave the function. That's why I strongly recommend introducing a extra property.